# Answer a Question, then Vote to Close. Delete my answer?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

A question came up on SO, which was answered by several people.  It was later discovered that the question was a dupe, and Votes to Close started coming in.

One of the people who posted an answer then commented to the effect that:

"I agree that's a dupe, and I voted to close, but I'm not going to delete my answer because there's no harm."

Should the poster delete their answer?

Comment: That guy's comment is pretty weak.  His argument should be "I posted a helpful answer," not "there is no harm in leaving it."

Comment: Note also that in case of a dupe, a useful answer might be merged into the existing question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Unless the answer is a direct copy-pasta, chances are there is a little bit of difference between the two, and while they may come to the same conclusion, more information is always better.

Even if the question gets closed, the answer cannot harm anything, in the worst case, someone saw something they already knew, and in other cases, someone learned something.

Comment: Copy-pasta? You haven't had lunch yet, have you?

Comment: @JohnDibling mmmm... pasta....

Comment: +1 - The only people really concerned about people not deleting those answers are people worried about rep. When you ignore rep -- barring any normal issues that may affect answer quality -- it's clear the information is helpful.